# how to know the lowest cuda toolkit version that supports for one specific gpu like gtx1080

Tags: gpu, nvidia

For a specific gpu like gtx1080, I want to know that which cuda toolkit versions support for it. I have scanned the official website of nvidia, but find no specific result.

Answer (score 0):

You could first check the Computing Capability (CC) of GTX1080 in the following site. It is CC 6.1.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Then check the CUDA doc below to see if it is in the supported CC list of the current version of CUDA 7.5. It is not.

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#compute-capabilities

So it should be supported by a future release. Currently the coming release is CUDA 8. You will find it in its document.

---

If you are not sure about the version of the doucments, you could find the documents associated with a specific CUDA installation, such as

```
/usr/local/cuda-7.5/doc
```

The help message of CUDA compiler also gives the supported CC list.

```
$ nvcc --help
--gpu-code <code>,...                      (-code)                           
        Specify the name of the NVIDIA GPU to assemble and optimize PTX for.
        nvcc embeds a compiled code image in the resulting executable for each specified
        <code> architecture, which is a true binary load image for each 'real' architecture
        (such as sm_20), and PTX code for the 'virtual' architecture (such as compute_20).
        During runtime, such embedded PTX code is dynamically compiled by the CUDA
        runtime system if no binary load image is found for the 'current' GPU.
        Architectures specified for options '--gpu-architecture' and '--gpu-code'
        may be 'virtual' as well as 'real', but the <code> architectures must be
        compatible with the <arch> architecture.  When the '--gpu-code' option is
        used, the value for the '--gpu-architecture' option must be a 'virtual' PTX
        architecture.
        For instance, '--gpu-architecture=compute_35' is not compatible with '--gpu-code=sm_30',
        because the earlier compilation stages will assume the availability of 'compute_35'
        features that are not present on 'sm_30'.
        Allowed values for this option:  'compute_20','compute_30','compute_32',
        'compute_35','compute_37','compute_50','compute_52','compute_53','sm_20',
        'sm_21','sm_30','sm_32','sm_35','sm_37','sm_50','sm_52','sm_53'.
```

Comment: What I see is that the CC in this doc shows some features it supports for but it is not connected with the version of cuda and the doc is an independent guide file that is not connected of some specific version of cuda. So I am still confused.

Comment: @luohao You could find the version number at the root of the document site. http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html